# Stellar life cycle flow chart with mass conditions and time scales

Tags: star, black-hole, supernova, stellar-evolution, neutron-star

I remember that in my nuclear astrophysics lecture a decade ago, our lecturer drew a large flow chart like diagram of stellar evolution in dependence of the mass of the star (in solar units) on the black-board. I found [one from Wikipedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/Star_Life_Cycle_Chart.jpg) which is close to the one I remember, but less detailed than the one I remember. The content of the linked chart is summarized in my following sketch:
[image]

Sadly, neither me nor my former classmates recall which text book or publication the diagram came from, we suspect it was a composition of many sources. The diagram came with a brief explanation of each mass threshold, and it also outlined the governing equations in the respective stellar state. I also remember that there were rough approximates of the time scales of the respective state given.

Maybe somebody can help me out with alternative search terms, references, or a textual answer briefly summarizing the conditions and the state-of-the-art error bars for the mass thresholds and timescales?

#### Related

- [The life course for a massive star from birth to death using the HR Diagram](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/1261/the-life-course-for-a-massive-star-from-birth-to-death-using-the-hr-diagram) and it comments are helpful, but only slightly related
- [What are the equations governing stellar evolution (Luminosity, Mass, Temperature, Radius)](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/27203/what-are-the-equations-governing-stellar-evolution-luminosity-mass-temperatur) touches one aspect of what I am after
- [A flowchart from Stephan et al. 2019](https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/stephan.98/research.html) outlining the outcomes of binary stellar evolution in the galactic center comes with the right amount of details, but is not for general star evolution.

### Edit from 2021-01-22

To make answering easier, I quickly layed out the existing diagram as [BPMN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Process_Model_and_Notation) which is editable e.g. with [this freely available editor](https://camunda.com/download/modeler/). The source code is available via https://pastebin.com/mrafLWa0 - please feel free to reuse, expand and distribution my diagram, just make you comment here where and what for.

Comment: This is not the one, I suppose?
https://www.khanacademy.org/humanities/big-history-project/stars-and-elements/how-were-stars-formed/a/infographic-life-cycles-of-the-stars

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My slapdash (and perhaps messy because I rendered it in PowerPoint) attempt at addressing stellar evolution. Open the flowchart in a new tab in fullscreen to see a better rendering of it.

[image: Stellar Evolution]

Comment: Do you have one or two references which you have based your nice and detailed chart on?